# How do I remove the zoom icon that appears when hovering over image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site that uses [this bootstrap theme](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/mimity-online-shop-template-WB094DPGC). When the mouse hovers over any image a zoom icon appears - how do I remove it?

I have tried removing `class="zoomIcon"` and looked on this site as well as searching on Google.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="product-main-image-container">
  <img src="../../images/products/prod1.png" alt="" class="product-loader" style="display: none;">
  <span class="thumbnail product-main-image" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <img src="../../images/products/prod1.png" alt="">
    <img src="../../images/products/prod1.png" class="zoomImg" 
         style="position: absolute; top: -0.0456852791878173px; left: -1.23350253807107px; opacity: 0; width: 400px; height: 400px; border: none; max-width: none; max-height: none;">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Someone commented needing to see the css - I don't know which css I need to show?

Comment: .product-main-image{ cursor: zoom-in; cursor: -webkit-zoom-in; cursor: -moz-zoom-in } it is attached to this

Comment: check there: http://screencast.com/t/NcdCxnrrW4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override this cursor behavior by either modifying the CSS that is making it happen (it looks like a CSS file called style.css) or by writing your own rule to make it stop.

The rule is on `.product-main-image` in line 432 of the style.css file, and to overwrite it, you would need a rule like this:

`.product-main-image{cursor:default;}` or [any other cursor style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) you wish

Answer (score 5):

You can add this to your CSS:

```
<style>
img:hover {
cursor: default;
}
</style>
```

I hope this helped you!

Comment: Thank you. This does work although the zoom icon appears for a split second before disappearing - any idea how I stop this? FYI I put this code in the site css...

Comment: try changing it to `img:hover, .product-main-image-container`

Answer (score 2):

class product-main-image has the zoom icon:

```
.product-main-image{ 
   cursor: zoom-in; cursor: -webkit-zoom-in; cursor: -moz-zoom-in 
}
```

http://screencast.com/t/NcdCxnrrW4

Just remove this class from the span or change the cursor on this class to something else http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is not from a class.

```
img:hover{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Unrelated : You shouldn't leave the 'alt' tags empty, they are important to accessibility and SEO.

Comment: Don't link to w3schools.

Comment: Im just upvoting to cancel that out

Comment: I can't even downvote if I wanted to, I don't have enough reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS cursor property.

Then you can just assign it to default on hover

```
img:hover {
cursor: default;
}
```